# Python urllib: How to pass client side installed certificate in cert store while making a POST request?

Tags: python, urllib

This is what I usually do in powershell to make a POST request:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Certificate (ls Cert:\CurrentUser\my |Where {$_.subject -eq "CN=mycertname"})
```

I'm trying to emulate this in python using urllib (I must use client libraries hence not using Request)

This is my code so far:

```
url = "https://x"

    body =  {
    "x":  {"x": "x" }
    }
    params = json.dumps(body).encode('utf8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=params,
                                 headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    print(response.read().decode('utf8'))
```

I'm not able to find how to pass the client certificate as is done above in the powershell script using urllib?

Comment: Have you looked into capath and cafile paramaters to urllib.request.urlopen()? https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: yes but I'm not able to get it to work. How do I define the capath to point to certificate store on Windows? any examples would help tremendously. Unfortunately I couldn't find any on internet.